# How to get my private key for exporting APNS certificates in new mac

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, keychain

I'm trying to export my apps production APNS certificate as p12 file.
But i don't have in my keychain the private key.
Last time i exported it was on an old mac about a year ago.
How can i get the private key for exporting?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. You have to revoke the old certificate from your Apple developer account and create a new one on your new Mac.

Comment: will my push notifications be disabled between the time i revoke and the time i renew?

Comment: No, it wont be disabled. Once you get a new APNS cert you have to upload it to the system that you are using to send the push payload to the APNS though.